# Get Authenticatable Users from database in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my Laravel project, default User extend as follows :

```
class User extends Authenticatable{
  use Notifiable;

  protected $fillable = [
      'id','name', 'email', 'password','type',
  ];

  protected $hidden = [
      'password', 'remember_token',
  ];
}
```

When I'm trying to get all registered users using this,

```
$user = User::all();
return $user;
```

> [{"id":0,"name":"sdfsd","email":"sdsdc@fdcs.gfhf","type":"a","created_at":"2016-12-11 19:44:39","updated_at":"2016-12-11 19:44:39"},{"id":0,"name":"dcsdc","email":"dsd@dscsdc.lll","type":"a","created_at":"2016-12-12 12:14:42","updated_at":"2016-12-12 12:14:42"}]

I got all the users but without their user ids.Id give as '0'.

And when I'm trying with 'where' constrain it gives a Exception.

So can I use User as a Eloquent model? How do I retrieve user table info in Laravel?

Comment: What kind of exception are you getting?

Comment: Provide proper/full code for travel to cause

Comment: Edited. I get above result when use `User::all()` but id shown as 0. I have checked db and they are not 0.
And using `User::where('id', "NPC0001")` I get error saying 'ErrorException in helpers.php line 519:
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string'

Comment: the "id" column shouldn't be in your fillable array, this is a security risk.

Comment: ID is not a auto increment id. I have changed it to a string. In my app user have to give it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find `public $incrementing = true;` into *Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php* path file and update it with `false` and check.

You can get the more detail about same from [Eloquent Model Conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)
Hope this should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks. it worked for getting all users. can I use where in this also..?

Comment: You can use this into your model while eloquent.

Comment: Glad to help you!

Answer (score 1):

You must set `$incrementing` to false on your model.

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

Eloquent assumes that the primary key is an incrementing integer value, which means that by default the primary key will be cast to an `int` automatically.

If you wish to use a non-incrementing or a non-numeric primary key you must set the public `$incrementing` property on your model to `false`.

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I think this will help me